# How to find closest <i>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML Code is as follow :

```
  <div class="listitems">
         user1@mail.com
    <a style="float: right;vertical-align: top;" data-recom-user="3" data-recom-mile="4">
      <i class="icon-eye-open"></i>
    </a>
    <i style="float: right;vertical-align: top;" data-irecom-done="false" data-irecom-user="3" data-irecom-mile="4" class="icon-hand-up" title="Recommend this user"></i>
    </div>
```

i have trigger click event on `<a>` in event handler function i want to access closest `<a>`

i tried `$(this).closest("<i>")` in this i got `<i class="icon-eye-open"></i>` how i can get

```
<i style="float: right;vertical-align: top;" data-irecom-done="false" data-irecom-user="3" data-irecom-mile="4" class="icon-hand-up" ></i>
```

Element so that i can change some some attributes of it.

Comment: "*[I] have trigger click event on `<a>` in event handler function [I] want to access closest `<a>`*" - Should the second `<a>` have been `<i>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your HTML markup, you can use [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) instead:

```
$(this).siblings('i')
```

or:

```
$(this).next()
```

Also, note that `closest()` will traverse up the DOM tree, this method is not using to find the child elements

Answer (score 2):

For getting inner anchor tag:

```
$(this).find("i")
```

For sibling:

```
$(this).siblings("i")
```

Comment: i have many same   <div class="listitems"> so no problem for that

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest("<i>")

<i class="icon-eye-open"></i>

$(this).find("i .icon-hand-up")

<i style="float: right;vertical-align: top;" data-irecom-done="false" data-irecom-user="3" data-irecom-mile="4" class="icon-hand-up" ></i>

$(this).find("i .icon-hand-up").attr('','') ; // you can change the attribute
```

or

```
 $(this).parent().find("i:last").attr('','');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".listitems a").click(function () {
        var sss = $(this).find('i');
        alert(sss.text());
    });
});
```